# Error: safari can't connect to the server "localhost"

Tags: macos

I am using leaflet(java script library) for making web mapping applications in my mac os Sierra version 10.12.5 using sublime text but the problem I am getting is that I am not able to connect to the local host in safari.

need guidance.

Comment: What software are you using for the webserver?

Comment: Hi, I am using Apache.

Comment: I think we are only able to help you if you provide more information. What have you tried? Is your server really running, is http://localhost returning a response etc.?